# Find expected time to reach a state in a Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains

Consider a Markov chain
$ (X_n)_{n\geq 0}  $
with state space $E$, initial distribution $p(0)$ and transition probability matrix
$P$ given by
$E = \{0, 1, 2\}, p(0) = [1\;\; 0\;\; 0]$ and

$$ P=   \begin{bmatrix}1/2 & 1/3 & 1/6\\0 & 2/3 & 1/3 \\0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Find $E[T]$ for $T = \min(n, X_n = 2).$

I know how to solve this in the usual way but I'm wondering about this solution:

$$E[T] = E[Y \mbox{ with }p=1/2] + (1/3) 0 + (2/3)  E[Y\mbox{ with }p = 1/3] = 2 + 0 + (2/3)3 = 4$$

where $Y$ should be the discrete waiting time random variable.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go from state $0$ to state $2$, we have to first *leave* state $0$.
Define $T^*=\inf(n\geq 0: X_n\in\{1,2\})$, so that $T^*\leq T.$ The additional number of steps needed to reach state $2$ after time $T^*$ depends on where we land in $\{1,2\}$, that is, on our new starting point $X_{T^*}.$ Putting it all together gives
$$E[T]=E[T^*]+E[T\mid X_{T^*}=2]\,P(X_{T^*}=2)+E[T\mid X_{T^*}=1]\,P(X_{T^*}=1).$$
Since the first state visited in $\{1,2\}$ is twice as likely to be $1$ as compared to $2$, we get 
$$E[T]=E[T^*]+E[T\mid X_{T^*}=2]\,\left({1\over 3}\right)+E[T\mid X_{T^*}=1]\left({2\over 3}\right).$$

Now, $E[T\mid X_{T^*}=2]=0$ since we start  in state $2$. Also,
$T^*$ is a geometric random variable with $p=1/2$ and so $E[T^*]=2.$
Finally, starting in state $1$, the time to hit state $2$ is a geometric
random variable with $p=1/3$, and so $E[T\mid X_{T^*}=1]=3.$
This gives
$$E[T]=2+ 0\left({1\over 3}\right)+ 3\left({2\over 3}\right)=4.$$

Comment: Thanks!. Good stuff. A crystal clear explanation!

Comment: @JKnecht Glad to help out.

Comment: Lets say we have a 4*4 matrix instead. This method easily extends to larger matrices? , and in the 4*4 case just by adding to $$E[T]= ...+ E[T^*_*]+E[T^*_*\mid X_{T^*_*}=v]\,\left({a\over b}\right)+E[T\mid X_{T^*_*}=w]\left({c\over d}\right).$$ if you understand what i mean. Sorry about the ter latex...im still trying to learn that. (And this T is a newly defined T in a similar way as the T*.)