# First time two independent Markov chains reach same state

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, conditional-expectation, markov-process

> Let $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ two independent Markov chains with the
> same state space $\{0,1,2\}$ and same transition probability matrix:
> $$ P=\begin{pmatrix} 0.5&0.25&0.25\\ 0.25&0.25&0.5\\ 0&0.5&0.5 \end{pmatrix} $$
>
> Define $T=\inf\{n: X_n=Y_n\}$. Assuming $X_0=0$ and $Y_0=2$, find
> $\mathbb{E}[T]$ and $\mathbb{P}[X_T=2]$.

I think I know how to compute the probability, but I'm having trouble computing the expectation of $T$.

**My attempt:** I thought it would be easy if I consider
$$\mathbb{E}[T] = \sum_{i=0}^{2} \mathbb{E}[T\vert X_T = i]\cdot \mathbb{P}[X_T = i]$$

since the probability I need to compute in the first exercise is involved. So the only thing is left to compute is $\mathbb{E}[T\vert X_T = i]$ for $i=0,1,2$. I know how to solve this expected value if there's only one Markov chain involved, let's say if we want to know the first time $X_t = 2$ since $X_0 = 0$, using a recurrence argument, but I'm stuck when the problem involves two Markov chains.

On the other hand, I found [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576092/find-expected-time-to-reach-a-state-in-a-markov-chain?rq=1) solving the analogous expected value for only one Markov chain, in a more direct way, without using conditional expected value, but I'm having trouble trying to apply a similar argument in this case.

Any help would be appreciatted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $ET=\sum P(T>n)=\sum P(X_i \neq Y_i: 1\leq i \leq n)$.

Comment: How would it be possible to calculate $P(X_{i}\neq Y_{i}, 1\le i \le n)$? I feel like it's hard